# How to get some documents of array in MongoDB

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query, spring-data-mongodb, mongodb-java

I have collection "users" where username , password,questions are stored .  "questions"  is an array of documents . I would like to get all  users with some questions i.e  username , password and an array of questions (some part) How can i do that   from console or java ?   [image]

Here i want to get username , password and first document of questions which is {question:"dawdaw",answered:0}

Comment: Don't use images to provide code samples. Include the code itself (formatted as code) so that others can easily copy and paste it to reproduce the problem themselves.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3985214/retrieve-only-the-queried-element-in-an-object-array-in-mongodb-collection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use slice like this

```
db.users.find({},{"questions":{$slice:1}})
```

Hope it will help

Answer (score 1):

Use **[`$elemMatch`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/)** projection to get the desired result. The following **[`find()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/#db.collection.find)** operation queries for all documents where the **[`$elemMatch`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/)** projection returns only the first matching element of the `questions` array where the `question` field has a value of `"dawdaw"` and `answered` has `0` value:

```
db.users.find({},
    { 
        "username": 1, "password": 1,
        "questions": { 
            "$elemMatch": { 
                "question" : "dawdaw",
                "answered" : 0
            } 
        } 
    }
);
```

From the sample given, the operation returns the following document:

```
/* 0 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("561a84ffaa233b38d803509a"),
    "username" : "asd@mail.ru",
    "password" : "asd",
    "questions" : [ 
        {
            "question" : "dawdaw",
            "answered" : 0
        }
    ]
}
```